# Evaluating Free Monads with Except transformer

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to add exception handling to my free monad, but I can't catch anything that's thrown from the evaluator. So far, I added Except the same way I have other transformers:

```
data TestFunctor a = Test a deriving(Functor)

runTest :: FT TestFunctor (Except Int) a -> Either Int a
runTest = runIdentity . runExceptT . iterT evalTest

evalTest :: TestFunctor (Except Int a) -> Except Int a
evalTest (Test next) = throwError 2 *> next
```

But when running it:

```
> runTest (catchError (throwError 0) (const $ pure ()))
Right ()
> runTest (catchError (liftF $ Test ()) (const $ pure ()))
Left 2
```

Is there a way to allow expressions in the free monad catch errors from the evaluator?

I'm using the `Control.Monad.Trans.Free.Church` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When building an `FT TestFunctor (Except Int)`, the `catchError` happens before you can even start interpreting it with `runTest`. If we temporarily switch to `FreeT` we can see what's going on. We are going to evaluate all of the following:

```
            throwError 0                      :: FreeT TestFunctor (Except Int) ()
catchError (throwError 0) (const $ pure ())   :: FreeT TestFunctor (Except Int) ()
            liftF $ Test ()                   :: FreeT TestFunctor (Except Int) ())
catchError (liftF $ Test ()) (const $ pure () :: FreeT TestFunctor (Except Int) ())
```

When we throw an error we get the error wrapped in `FreeT`.

```
>             throwError 0                      :: FreeT TestFunctor (Except Int) ()
FreeT (ExceptT (Identity (Left 0)))
```

Catching the error replaces it in the free tree

```
> catchError (throwError 0) (const $ pure ())   :: FreeT TestFunctor (Except Int) ()
FreeT (ExceptT (Identity (Right (Pure ()))))
```

On the other hand, when we `liftF` `Test ()` it is returned to the `Right` in `ExceptT`, as is the `()` it holds.

```
>             liftF $ Test ()                   :: FreeT TestFunctor (Except Int) ())
FreeT (ExceptT (Identity (Right (Free (Test (FreeT (ExceptT (Identity (Right (Pure ()))))))))))
                          | The one above is a return, the one below is a throw
FreeT (ExceptT (Identity (Left 0)))
```

When you `catchError`s on this, it doesn't do anything, it was already successful.

```
> catchError (liftF $ Test ()) (const $ pure () :: FreeT TestFunctor (Except Int) ())
FreeT (ExceptT (Identity (Right (Free (Test (FreeT (ExceptT (Identity (Right (Pure ()))))))))))
```

#### Add the operations to the tree

If you want to throw and catch errors in the evaluation of the free tree, add the throw and catch operations to what your functor can represent.

```
data ExceptOp e a
  = Throw e
  | Catch a (e -> a)
  deriving (Functor)
```

To interpret an operation that supports throwing and catching exceptions, we replace `Throw` with `throwError` and `Catch` with `catchError`

```
runTest :: FT (ExceptOp Int) Identity a -> Either Int a
runTest = runIdentity . runExceptT . iterTM evalExcept

evalExcept :: (Monad m) => ExceptOp e (ExceptT e m a) -> ExceptT e m a
evalExcept (Throw e) = throwError e
evalExcept (Catch next f) = catchError next f
```

This catches the exception when we evaluate it

```
> runTest (wrap $ Catch (liftF $ Throw 0) (const $ pure ()))
Right ()
```

Comment: For some reason I thought it worked by substitution, thanks for clearing this up!